# Deprecate Managed Metadata Term

Tags: managed-metadata, custom-form, edit-form

I have a managed metadata term that I want to deprecate. I was under the impression that if I deprecate a managed metadata term that existing list items that use that value will keep that value but it can't be chosen when creating new list items. Is that assumption/understanding correct?

If my above assumption is correct, then I have an issue. I am creating a list item using a custom add form set the field named "Change Type" to have the managed metadata value "Analytical". Everything saves fine. If I then deprecate "Analytical", when I open my custom edit form, "Analytical" is underlined/highlighted in red and if I make changes on my custom edit form, the changes aren't saved. Is that the behavior I should expect? I was expecting the "Change Type" field to still have analytical since it was a valid choice when it was created. Below is the markup for my managed metadata field on the custom edit form.

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff11{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Change_x0020_Type" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff11',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Change_x0020_Type')}"/>
```